# Get 403 after redirection URL ACS SSO 6 authentification Via CI 3

Tags: php, saml-2.0

In order to authenticate the User by the SSO mechanism:
I get a 403 response after a redirection from the IDP server (having the saml 2.0 response) to SP.
here is the body of the error:

> An error has occurred
> The action you requested is not authorized.

I'm using Code Igniter 3 for MVC framework

Can you help me !

no idea

Comment: We can't help with what you provided. What SAML library are you using? What attributes do you require? Is the 403 because the session isn't being initiated or because the routed path is incorrect?

Comment: The URL is behind a login apparently... I guess it's the ReturnURL to which the IdP wants to send the user.. did you establish the session in the application properly?

Comment: I use the "SAML PHP Toolkit" library. Was an attribute missing in the configuration file to correct the error?
Perhabs, i want to add this block in the post returnet by idp:
<input type="hidden" name="<?= csrf_token() ?>" value="<?= csrf_hash() ?>" id="msg_csrf"/>  
@honk der Hase ...Yes, that's the return URL the IdP wants to send the user to but I still got a 403 return!

Comment: And is the ReturnURL in a protected area?

Comment: @Honk der Hase
Yes, the returned URL is an protected area ( HTTPS )

Comment: Then it's likely that the session is not established in a logged in state... the IdP has authenticated the user, you must log him into your application (you trust the IdP, so you'll create a session for the user and log him in without password).